# Is there a health endpoint for the Rocketchat server

Tags: rocket.chat

Is there a health endpoint for the Rocketchat server, we would like to use this to monitor availability of the server.

https://forums.rocket.chat/t/rocket-chat-on-docker-no-health-check/9106 says there isn't an endpoint available

Answer (score 0):

There is not.

But you could build yourself a channel, which can have similar/same purpose. Upon receiving a Ping, to reply with `OK` or `Pong` or `Success` or anything that you expect, and if the channel does not reply in a given predefined timeout, that would trigger an alert that the service is down/slow..

Answer (score 0):

My RocketChat container (image: docker.io/rocketchat/rocket.chat) has a health endpoint.

I'm not an expert in RocketChat but I think this PR introduced it: https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/pull/27026 (Not sure what is meant by data stream and if it is an overall health check.)

It is also indicated in RocketChat's Helm-Charts: https://github.com/RocketChat/helm-charts/blob/master/rocketchat/templates/chat-deployment.yaml